# In gmail, Add to calendar button not working properly in ics file header

Tags: calendar, gmail, icalendar

I sent invitation mail with attachment of .ics file. but when mail is sent to the user, User have a .ics file header with message body and a attachment link

In ics file heade, when user click on add calendar button to add event in the calendar. it does not add event in the calendar and just loading after some time shows the message 
'Calendar could not load the data. Please try reloading later.'

Here is my .ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN   
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20190514
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20190515
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:Vrandawan Dham Colony\, Ujjain\, Madhya Pradesh 456010\, 
India
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:AllDRepeatDaily_times
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`
```

I removed UID from Ics file but it does not work for me

I am thankful, If anyone help me regarding this issue

Comment: None of your tags appeared to be related to the question. I've edited them. Hopefully now your question will be seen by people who might have more relevant knowledge.

Comment: Thank You  ADyson

Comment: Hey guys, 
removing ;VALUE=DATE from DTSTART and DTEND works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works for me

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN

VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190514
DTEND:20190515
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION: 
India
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:AllDRepeatDaily_times
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`